# How to identify if create read replica action is complete and finished

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cli

I am trying to create a read replica of the production database and then I want to promote the read replica to a test database.

I have used this awscli command to create a read replica

```
aws rds create-db-instance-read-replica --db-instance-identifier test-database --source-db-instance-identifier production-database --region eu-central-1
```

I know I cannot issue a promote read replica command immediately as I would get an error.

```
bash-3.2$ aws rds promote-read-replica --db-instance-identifier test-database --region eu-central-1

An error occurred (InvalidDBInstanceState) when calling the PromoteReadReplica operation: DB Instance is not in an available state.
```

How can I check if the read replica is created successfully so I can issue a promote read replica command?

I tried to query the events for the database but it is returning empty.

```
bash-3.2$ aws rds describe-events --source-identifier test-database --source-type db-instance
{
    "Events": []
}
```

I am trying to do this in the Jenkins pipeline so it has to be checked programmatically.

Kindly advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [describe-db-instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/describe-db-instances.html) and create a simple while-based waiter for the replica to be available.

For example:

```
while true; do 

    db_status=$(aws rds describe-db-instances \
                --db-instance-identifier test-database \
                --query 'DBInstances[0].DBInstanceStatus' \
                --output text)
                
    [[ $db_status != "available" ]] \
        && (echo $db_status; sleep 5) \
        || break    
done

echo "Finally ${db_status}"
```

The above will check the status of `test-database` every 5 seconds until its `available`.

Answer (score 0):

i m trying to continue the above script by adding parameter group and reboot the read replica .

```
 db_status=$(aws rds describe-db-instances \
                --db-instance-identifier db-replica \
                --profile xxx \
                --region us-west-2 \
                --query 'DBInstances[0].DBInstanceStatus' \
                --output text)               
    [[ $db_status != "available" ]] \
        && (echo $db_status; sleep 15)\
        || break 
    
 echo "Finally ${db_status}"
if [ $db_status == "available" ]
    then
        echo "replica created successfully"
        echo "Rebooting replica"
        aws rds reboot-db-instance --db-instance-identifier db-replica 
        sleep 5;
else
   echo "replica rebooted successfully"
fi
       
exit 1
```